# Navigating and updating content in a CodeIgniter application

Tags: codeigniter, menu

I am using CI with Twitter Bootstrap for a basic site:

In my main layout view this is how the main content area is setup:

```
    <div class="container-fluid"> 
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span1"></div>
            <div class="span8">
                <?php echo $this->load->view($subview); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="span3" id="sidebar">
                <?php echo $this->load->view($this->global_data['sidebarview']); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

One sidebar view is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="sidebar-about">  
    <div class="well sidebar-nav">  
        <ul class="nav nav-list">  
            <li class="nav-header"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i>&nbsp;More about us</li>  
            <li class="active"><a href="about">Who are we?</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Why we did it?</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">What we promise?</a></li>  
            <li class="nav-header"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;Services</li>  
            <li><a href="#">Free</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>  
        </ul>  
    </div><!--/.well -->  
</div><!--/span-->
```

Every link in this sidebar i want to update the div with class="span8" from my main layout.

How should i do that? Should i use ajax calls to update the content of the span8 div? or just create more methods in about controller?

Comment: If you want to update the content without using a traditional new page load, then yes you should use an ajax solution to retrieve and replace the content.

Comment: So there is no other way that i am not aeware of, as i am coming from "trasditional" world and things change every day....You could elaborate as an answer and mark it if you want.

Comment: A traditional new page load means you click the link and it goes to a new URL, new page, new page load. It's the way most of the internet works. If you want to load new content onto a page without navigating away from that URL, then you need some sort of ajax solution. If you have a more specific question about that, then ask it, but I'm not going to teach you ajax requests 101.

Comment: No you are not, i didn't mean that with 'elaborate', i just wanted a catch up on how 'internet' feels right now about updating content in pages...As i understood from your comment if i want ajax i should use jquery for example and update my main div with a .html($data) command. And that $data could come from an ajax jquery call to a custom codeigniter method..yes?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really where you should be asking questions about trends and/or how the internet feels. Discussion forums are more appropriate for that. But yes, that's one way to get started with ajax.